# Android Beacon Library - didRangeBeaconsInRegion Method

Tags: android, beacon

I have just a theory question. 
When using the method  didRangeBeaconsInRegion of the Android Beacon Library, this method returns all the beacons found nearby, eventhough they are diferent regions (UUID), or it just returns the beacons of the same region (UUID) that you defined?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up two different Region objects, region1 and region2, and start ranging on them, you will get two callbacks each second.

The first callback will give you the list of beacons matching region1 and the second will give you the list of beacons matching region2.

This behavior is not specific to UUID, but Region.  So if you define a wildcard region that does not specify the UUID, a single callback will return all beacons seen.  If you define a region with a UUID specified, the callback for that region will contain a list including only beacons matching that UUID.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand!